# Google Forms and Responses for Multiple Checkbox Grid

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm looking for a way to eliminate checkboxes from a multiple-choice grid after someone submits a form. The multiple-choice grid option allows the user to select any box from any row and any column.

for this example, I have a 5x5 grid and if a user selects one or more checkboxes from any column or any row I would like for the form to show only the boxes that are available after each form submission.

so if row 1 column 2 is checked and submitted, the next time the form is viewed it should show row 1 column 2 as unavailable. How can I accomplish this using Google Forms and Google Sheets? Is there a formula that is needed in sheets that will get the desired results?

Comment: Could you please share a test form and sheet? It would help to understand better what you are trying to achieve. Also, what I could understand from your question, your goal is when submitting an answer from a form, set that value in the form as "unavailable" so other users will not able to select that same option again, is that correct?

Comment: Here is the Form and response sheet of the 5x5 grid i would like to share with you. I'm trying to create a Grid that will eliminate check boxes after a user submits there choice(s). https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1AQhUKdSILNyBb3av6EBBYrO5vsO31HlQia8dCxW0n6Y/edit?usp=sharing           https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mtj9pvndO5TUup3iUwM567JONxc3Me1xFk3ue0znKx0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not possible because when using Tick box grids you can only set or eliminate a whole row/column. The methods [setRows(rows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#setrowsrows) and [setColumns(columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#setcolumnscolumns) from the class [CheckboxGridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item) will accept an array of values to build the Tick box grid, there is no method to set/eliminate an specific checkbox/value.

As a recommendation, depending on your project and what your final goal is, you could have the checkboxes directly in your Spreadsheet.