# Setting the row Choices in a Google Form Multi Choice Grid Item?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have used the [Setting the Column Choices in a Google Form Multi Choice Grid Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145728/google-forms-and-responses-for-multiple-checkbox-grid) topic to produce a Apps Script which produces a dynamic Google Form Grid Item based on an underlying Google sheet.

A trigger runs on the google sheet, so that when a new record is entered, this should be replicated as a new row in the form item.

The problem I am having is if I use an array formula to populate the setRows attribute at line 20 (`namesList.setRows([studentNames])`) of the code, the form item is produced but each of the names is produced as a single concatenated line (i.e. Person 1, Person2, Person3 etc).

[image: grid-not-working]

If I hard code the person elements in the setRows element at line 21 (`namesList.setRows(['Person1','Person2','Person3','Person4','Person5','Person6','Person7'])`) of the code, the form item is produced, with (in this instance) 7 lines, with each record having its own line. i.e.

Person1

Person2

Person3

[image: Grid Working]

I don't want to use a hard coded list as the list of person names could increase on a regular basis, so need to use an array to produce the list but then use the array in the setRows element.

```
function updateForm(){
// call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("FakeFormID");
  var namesList = form.getItemById("FakeFormItemID").asGridItem();

// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("FakeSheetName");

// grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row
  var namesValues = names.getRange(2, 1, names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var studentNames = [];

// convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)   
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      studentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];

// populate the drop-down with the array data
    namesList.setRows([studentNames]) //creates a concatenated list
    namesList.setRows(['Person1','Person2','Person3','Person4','Person5','Person6','Person7']) //creates individual lines but is hard coded
    namesList.setColumns(['1','2','3','4','5']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
studentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];
```

by

```
studentNames.push(namesValues[i][0]);
```

the above is to avoid that `studenNames` includes empty elements.

---

Also instead of `getMaxRows()` use `getLastRow()` as the last it's very likely that will make your script more efficient as usually a sheet includes empty rows at the bottom that under certain circumstances might be too many.

Comment: Thank you for that response, while it does clean up the code and make it more efficient it still leaves me with the initial issue that when using an array element to populate the setRows option the resultant elements are produced as a concatenated list and not an individual line for each item

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out already but the array will fill properly if you remove the brackets from studentNames:

```
namesList.setRows(studentNames)
```

instead of:
namesList.setRows([studentNames])